# Logic operators in AllowGroups in sshd_config

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, openssh, sshd

Is it possible to use logical operators in AllowGroups in sshd_config? The thing I want to achieve is to permit user to access server only when it belongs to two groups. ChatGPT gave me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNiqC.png) answer, but I'm not convinced to it...
I didn't find any other useful information, even in documentation.

Many thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by ChatGPT is pure nonsense - this tool is meant to produce
works that emulate human texts, but you should not treat it on the
same level as Google.

[sshd_config](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.1-RELEASE)
allows patterns in the AllowGroups directive, which are defined as:

> A pattern consists of zero or more non-whitespace characters, `*' (a wildcard that matches zero  or more characters), or` ?' (a wildcard that
> matches exactly one character).
>
> A pattern-list is a comma-separated list of patterns.  Patterns within
> pattern-lists may be negated by preceding them with an exclamation  mark
> (`!').

Specifically, the `|` and `&` operators are not included.

For your problem, you might be able to achieve the restriction to the
two groups by using the negation operator, such as:

```
DenyGroups !group1,!group2
```

So anyone who is either not in group1 *or* not in group2 is denied login.

Comment: Yes, I didn't even think that ChatGPT's answer is best option.
`!` will not work for me, because I need to match both groups, not one of them.
Anyway, your post answers my question. Thank you for clarification!

Comment: Logic laws says that "not ( (not group1) or (not group2) )" is the same as "group1 and group2". See [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: Sure, but `DenyGroups !group1,!group2` is not the same as `DenyGroups !(!group1,!group2)` and I can't do latter. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry to say, but you're wrong. Take some examples and you'll see.

Comment: Sure I will, thank you.